# Going from single screen app to tab based app in react-native-navigation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm wondering how to go from a single screen app, to a tab based app. There is one similar question on here which has no relevant answers.

Currently I'm doing this

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
      screen: 'Login',
      title: 'Login'
    }
  });

  Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
    tabs: [
      {
        label: 'tab1', 
        screen: 'Login', 
        icon: tab1Icon, 
        selectedIcon: tab1Icon, 
        },
        title: 'tab1', 
        navigatorStyle: {}, 
        navigatorButtons: {} 
      },
      {
        label: 'tab2',
        screen: 'tab2',
        icon: tab2Icon,
        selectedIcon: tab2Icon,
        title: 'tab2'
      },
       {
        label: 'tab3',
        screen: 'tab3',
        icon: tab3Icon,
        selectedIcon: tab3Icon,
        title: 'tab3'
      },
  });
```

So right now I'm simply covering the first tab with the Login screen (where I have hidden the tabs on that particular screen" and when I press the log in button I simply move up the stack to the tab1 screen where the tabs are visible.

So even though I have a startSingleScreenApp the app still starts from the tabBasedApp, so I'm not sure the startSingleScreenApp does anything.

Anyone with experience using this library who can tell me how to proceed?

Comment: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/old-example-redux/src/app.js is an old example app that is no longer maintained - but the logic demonstrated there is still correct. It should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Modal view for when a user logs in successfully, which will then, in turn present the TabNavigator.

Lets start with your entry point to the app, the `App.js` file:

```
import...

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <LoginScreen/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry...
```

This will present your `LoginScreen` upon launching the app and inside `LoginScreen.js`, is where you will store the Modal

```
import ...

class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      successfulLoginModalVisible: false
    }
  }

 setSuccessfulLoginModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({successfulLoginModalVisible: visible});
  }

...

  render() {
    return(
      <ViewContainer>
        <Modal
          animationType={"slide"}
          visible={this.state.successfulLoginModalVisible}
        >
          <SuccessfulLoginScreen onLogout={() => this.hideSuccessfulLoginModal()}/>
        </Modal>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Simply put, in react native, the modal will present itself depending on a boolean value which should be stored in the state (i.e. `this.state.successfulLoginModalVisible`).  To make this Modal visible, simply call the `setSuccessfulLoginModalVisible(true)` function (on a button press for instance)

Finally, lets take a look at `SuccessfulLoginScreen.js`:

```
import ...
export const MyAccountStack = StackNavigator({ //This stack will be used to manage the Tab1 stack

  MyAccount: { screen: MyAccountTab },
  ViewFollowers: { screen: ViewFollowersScreen },
  ViewFollowing: { screen: ViewFollowingScreen },
  EditAccount: { screen: EditAccountScreen },

});

export default tabNavigation = TabNavigator ({

  Tab1: {screen: MyAccountStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'My Account',
      }
  },
  Tab2: {screen: ...},
  Tab3: {screen: ...},
  }, {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        activeBackgroundColor: 'darkgrey',
    }
});
```

This logic will then allow you to maintain a stack for each of your individual tabs.

This is the approach i would take. Please note, I have been emphasizing my development on iOS; I have not checked out this behavior on Android (but i believe there shouldn't be much, if any, discrepancy). Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In react-native-navigation it is assumed you may call startSingleScreenApp and startSingleScreenApp multiple times.

For example, you would use this to start the App with your Login or Home screen:

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    // ...
})
```

Later, from a button either in that screen or in the Drawer, you may call:

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
    // ...
})
```

And the Navigator will start your tab-based interface, replacing the previous navigation stack.

Both can include the same Drawer config.

You can call startSingleScreenApp() again later to go to another single screen, and so forth. You're just replacing the navigator with new navigation stacks as you go.